# Slim framework -creating a route which will return a downloadable file stream

Tags: php, csv, slim-3

I have created the following Slim Framework route in `index.php`

`$app->get('/generatecsv', ShippingCSVGenerator::class . ':generateShippingCSV');`

The function `generateShippingCSV()` is correctly being called, however I would like to return a stream which should be downloadable via JS in whatever view it may be required.

```
public function generateShippingCSV()
{
    // ...some code here... //
    $out = fopen('dispatch.csv', 'w');
    foreach ($CSVArray as $fields) {
        fputcsv($out, $fields);
    }
    $stream = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\LazyOpenStream('dispatch.csv', 'r');
    $response->withBody($stream);
    return $response;
}
```

The function above creates the CSV correctly, however I don't want to create a file -I want to return the file stream.

*** edit ***

Adding:

```
return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/force-download')
    ->withBody($stream);
```

...made the file available whenever the route is accessed via the browser, but I would prefer to return a stream, rather than produce and return a physical file.

Comment: You can implements your own `StreamInterface` or use for example https://github.com/zamronypj/zzzstream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this. For example:

1. Extends Slim `Slim\Http\RequestBody` class

   ```
   <?php

   use Slim\Http\RequestBody;

   class CsvRequestBody extends RequestBody
   {
        public writeCsv(array $CSVArray) 
        {
             $this->rewind();
             foreach ($CSVArray as $fields) {
                 fputcsv($this->stream, $fields);
             }      
        } 
   }
   ```

   then in your code that output response

   ```
   $csvBody = new CsvRequestBody();
   $scvBody->writeCsv($CSVArray);
   return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/force-download')
                   ->withBody($csvBody);
   ```
2. Write data to `php://temp`, read it to a variable then write it to response body.

   ```
   $out = fopen('php://temp', 'w');
   foreach ($CSVArray as $fields) {
       fputcsv($out, $fields);
   }
   rewind($out);
   $csvData = stream_get_contents($out);
   fclose($out);

   $response->getBody()->rewind();
   $response->getBody()->write($csvData);
   return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
   ```